# Is the following statement true? If g = O(f) and h = O(f) then g = O(h) for all f,g,h

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, computation-theory

Does that statement follow Big O transitivity?
I am new to Big O notation and Time Complexity so I am struggling with the basics.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Think of the counterexample:

*f(n) = n<sup>3</sup>*

*g(n) = n<sup>2</sup>*

*h(n) = n*.

Indeed, *g = O(f)* and *h = O(f)*. But is *g = O(h)*?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to attack this problem is to leverage the definition of Big O. I say "good" because you'll be better off in the long run by developing a deeper understanding of the theory behind this question.

First, note that *f(n) = O(g(n)) if and only if f(n) ≤ c∙g(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> and some c > 0*.

Next, apply that definition to the statements in the question.

If *g(n) = O(f(n))* then *g(n) ≤ c<sub>0</sub>∙f(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> and some c<sub>0</sub> > 0*...

Similarly, if *h(n) = O(f(n))*, then *h(n) ≤ c<sub>1</sub>∙f(n)* ... etc.

So, given these two facts, are you able to prove that *g(n) = O(h(n))*? Well, what does that actually mean?

It means that (again!):

*g(n) ≤ c<sub>2</sub>∙h(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>2</sub> and some c<sub>2</sub> > 0*

So what you have is that:

g(n) is "less" than f(n)
h(n) is also "less" than f(n)

Can you conclude that g(n) is "less" than h(n)? No, you cannot. Now, after breaking this down and figuring out what you *think* the right answer is, you can try to find a counterexample (which has already been provided).

I generally take this approach when I'm trying to answer one of those tricky "True or False? If true, prove it. If false, give a counterexample" problems since I find that it enhances my understanding of the concepts that I'm studying!